# Cannot specify Http sink for serilog in appsettings with Serilog.Sinks.Http nuget package

Tags: c#, app-config, serilog

I had a serilog configuration in code like this:

```
            _seriLog = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .WriteTo.DurableHttpUsingTimeRolledBuffers("http://192.168.100.178:8080")
                .CreateLogger();
```

and wanted to change it to a config file. I added the Seriolog.Settings.AppSettings nuget package, and tried to follow the directions on github.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="serilog:minimum-level"  value="Verbose"/>
        <add key="serilog:using:Http" value="Serilog.Sinks.Http" />
        <add key="serilog:write-to:Http.requestUri" value="http://192.168.100.178:8080" />
    </appSettings>
    <startup>
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2" />
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

When I start the app, it hangs. There is no exception thrown, and the stack trace does not make sense to me. Here is the stack-trace for the LogManager thread:
[stack trace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j2Aa1.png)

Update: There was actually a exception thrown from the startup project: Could not load file or assembly 'Serilog.Sinks.Http'. See solution below.

Comment: have you tried setting up and looking at the [SelfLog](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Debugging-and-Diagnostics)?

Comment: No I had not. I just did now tho, and it is not giving any messages.

Comment: and just to confirm you've added .ReadFrom.AppSettings() to your logger configuration?

Comment: Yes I did. The minimum-level setting works fine and the log levels are changing on my ELK Stack log server. Just when I add the write-to setting in app.config, it freezes on startup.

Comment: Bear in mind the appsettings approach doesn't call your first method, it calls .WriteTo.Http([URL]) so have you tested that?

Comment: What you might find is a better approach, if you need to use the custom method, is to store the URL in app settings and then configure in code (like your first example)

Comment: Yes, I have tested both methods. I never thought of saving the IP in app settings. I may have to do that instead.

Comment: One thing that I have just spotted [here](https://github.com/FantasticFiasco/serilog-sinks-http/wiki/Durable-time-rolled-HTTP-sink) although Im not sure if this will work in app settings: Instead of serilog:write-to:Http.requestUri, try serilog:write-to:DurableHttpUsingTimeRolledBuffers.requestUri

Comment: I had tried that too. Both Http and DurableHttpUsingTimeRolledBuffers behave the same.

Comment: Hi, I'm the author of the sink HTTP sink. I don't run tests against Serilog.Settings.AppSettings, but I do officially support Serilog.Settings.Configuration. I'll see if I can reproduce your problem and seek a remedy for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There WAS in fact an exception getting thrown. I did not see this because my exception settings were changed accidentally. ProjectA complained that it could not find Serilog.Sinks.Http. ProjectA is a .net Framework project, and it was referencing ProjectB which is .net Standard. My logger implementation and Serilog packages are both inside ProjectB, which is why ProjectA depends on it. I found [this github issue](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/issues/1215), and added Serilog.Sink.Http nuget package to ProjectA. Fixed the problem instantly.

Answer (score 0):

I think you've forgotten to add `<add key="serilog:write-to:DurableHttpUsingTimeRolledBuffers" />` to your configuration. My configuration looks like this and seems to work as expected.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="serilog:using:Http" value="Serilog.Sinks.Http" />
    <add key="serilog:write-to:DurableHttpUsingTimeRolledBuffers" />
    <add key="serilog:write-to:DurableHttpUsingTimeRolledBuffers.requestUri" value="http://localhost:8080/log-events" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is still freezing on me. Here are my nuget package versions: Serilog 2.10.0-dev-01191, Serilog.Settings.AppSettings 2.2.2, Serilog.Sinks.Http 7.0.1. Is that what your are using? I can't think of anything else that could be different btw yours and mine.

Comment: You can find my sample application on https://github.com/FantasticFiasco/serilog-sinks-http-sample-dotnet-framework, in the branch called feat/serilog-settings-appsettings.